# Replace special characters from a string from an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, special-characters

Below is my code:

```
NSString *str = [EpiC objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\/"];
str = [[str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWant] componentsJoinedByString: @"\"];
NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

it is showing error as follow:
unknown escape sequence at this line:

```
NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\/"];
```

and unexpected '@' in program,at this line:

```
NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\"];
```

Comment: can you show your string `str`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik  FSJ\/6356232 this is the string, i want it to be  FSJ\6356232

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*unknown escape sequence* means you must escape the backslash with a second backslash.

```
NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\\/"];
```

The additional backslash solves the *unexpected '@' in program* error, too.

Answer (score 1):

do like

```
 NSString *str = @"FSJ\/6356232";
NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\\/"];
str = [[str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWant] componentsJoinedByString: @"\\"];
       NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

you get the output of

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Do as follow i am sure work for you.

```
 NSString *str = @"FSJ\/6356232";
 NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\\/"];
 str = [[str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWant] componentsJoinedByString: @"\\"];
       NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

Comment: what the difference between your answer and my answer

Comment: Sorry but i didn't show your ans while i will give the answer

Comment: it's Okay no problem